# Make Laravel's notIn validation rule case insensitive

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, validation

I am storing an array of strings in my database (db column type is JSON). There is a form that allows users to add a value to this array. I want to make sure there are no duplicates in this array. The [notIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) validation rule appears be the simplest solution to prevent duplicates but it is case sensitive. So when using notIn I am not able to prevent identical strings that have different capitalization.

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'choice' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn($choices)
    ]
]);
```

Does anyone have recommendation on how I should fix this validation so that the string comparison is case insensitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could lowercase your input data as well as your current data like this:

```
$input = request()->all();
$input['choice'] = array_map("strtolower", $input['choice']);
request()->validate($input, [
    'choice' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn(array_map("strtolower", $choices))
    ]
]);
```

Comment: this doesn't work because validate waits for a Request instance and the request()->all() method returns an array.

Comment: You are right ! I think I meant to use the Request's `validate` method (or the Validator's they are the same).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [Ramy Herria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215233/make-laravels-notin-validation-rule-case-insensitive/50215601#50215601), I was able to expand his answer to also work in a FormRequest class:

```
protected function validationData()
{
    $all = parent::validationData();
    //Convert request value to lowercase
    $all['choice'] = strtolower($all['choice']);
    return $all;
}

public function rules()
{
    $choices = $this->route('modelName')->choices;
    return [
        'choice' => [
            'required',
            //Also convert array to lowercase
            Rule::notIn(array_map('strtolower', $choices))
        ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own validation rule class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In;

class CaseInsensitiveInRule extends In implements Rule
{
    use ValidatesAttributes;
    private const FORMAT_FUNCTION = 'strtoupper';

    public function __construct(array $values)
    {
        $this->values = array_map(self::FORMAT_FUNCTION, $values);
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $value = call_user_func(self::FORMAT_FUNCTION, $value);

        return $this->validateIn($attribute, $value, $this->values);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return __('validation.invalid_value');
    }
}
```

and next you can create a object in your request class

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'status' => new CaseInsensitiveInRule(['active', 'deleted'])
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i know it is a little late, but for others i will suggest to use prepareForValidation method inside custom request class; like follow

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'choices' => strtolower($this->choices),
        ]);
    }
}
```

this way user input for choices are always lower case and the request itself is modified too.